# La tabla de datos de Vuetify no muestra datos

Tags: vue.js, asp, axios, vuetify

**Que esta pasando**
Sobre el back-end lo lista estoy utilizando postman por el metodo GET, tengo la herramienta en mi google chrome de vue y si llegan los datos en **data**, y si recibo los en el array, estoy utilizando de back asp.net 3.1, de front-end estoy utilizando Vuejs, Vuetify la version es la ultima vue(v2.6.11), estoy haciendo las peticiones http por medio de axios en la version (0.19.2).

Pero al final no me aparece ningún error en herramientas de desarrollador en **console** ni en **network** todo funciona bien si no pues no llegara a **data**.

**necesito** Que data-table me muestre los datos que están mi base de datos, ya que no los muestra.

```
  <v-data-table :headers="headers" :item="medium" class= "elevation-1">                    
                <template slot="headers" slot-scope="props">
                       <td class="justify-center layout px-0">
                        <v-icon small class="mr-2" @click="editItem(item)">edit</v-icon>   
                        <v-icon small @click="deleteItem(item)">delete</v-icon>
                        </td>   
                        <td>{{ props.mediumId }}</td>
                        <td>{{ props.personalInformationId }}</td>
                        <td>{{ props.medium1 }}</td>                       
                 </template>
                    <template v-slot:no-data>
                         <v-btn color="primary" @click="listar">Enciendelo Eduardo</v-btn>
                    </template>
  </v-data-table>
```

**Script**

```
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
    data: () => ({               
            dialog: false,
            headers: [
            { text: 'Opciones', value: 'opciones', sortable: false },
            { text: 'Medio de id', value: 'mediumId' },
            { text: 'Medio de persona', value: 'personalInformationId' },
            { text: 'Medio ', value: 'medium1' },
            ],
             medium:[ {
             editedIndex: -1,
             mediumId: '',
             personalInformationId: '',
             medium1:'' , 
             }
             ],
    }),

    computed: {
    formTitle () {
        return this.editedIndex === -1 ? 'Registrar' : 'Actualizar'
    },
    },
    watch: {
    dialog (val) {
        val || this.close()
    },
    },
    created () {
        this.listar();
    },

    methods: {
        listar (){
            let me=this;
            axios.get('api/Medium').then(function(response){
            //console.log(response);
             me.medium=response.data;
           }).catch(function(error){
             console.log(error);
            });
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

el problema lo tenia en mi metodo listar,

```
     methods: {
        listar (){
           let me=this;
            axios.get('api/Medium').then(function(response){
            //console.log(response.data);
             me.mediums=response.data.data;
           }).catch(function(error){
             console.log(error);
            });
    },
```

response es el objeto de respuesta axios.

response.data es el objeto de paginador asp.

response.data.data es la matriz de datos dentro del objeto paginador asp.